# External Store File

Tags: alpine.js

I've created an Alpine store like the example:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
 
Alpine.store('darkMode', {
    on: false,
 
    toggle() {
        this.on = ! this.on
    }
})
 
Alpine.start()
```

Is there a way I can export the store to an external file and import it, as you can do with plugins etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply create a separate `store.js` file with the store definition:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
 
Alpine.store('darkMode', {
    on: false,
 
    toggle() {
        this.on = ! this.on
    }
})
```

And from the `main.js` (or equivalent) import the `store.js` file:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

import './store.js'
 
Alpine.start()
```

(I used Vite for testing.)

Comment: https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store#registering-a-store